# Objective-C: Accessing integer value of a ViewController in View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to start a NSTimer in my UIView class called "ClockView" with a method as selector that manipulates an initial float which was declared in the ViewController "ClockViewController".

My ClockViewController declares `int timerIntWhite` as an integer (for example 500). My ClockView needs this Value for the `- (void)start` method which runs a method called `- (void)updateWhiteClock` every second:

```
- (void)start {

    timerIntWhite = PLEASE HELP ME AT THIS POINT!;
    randomTimerWhite = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0)target:self selector:@selector(updateWhiteClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Is it possible to access the integer of ClockViewController in ClockView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

In your `ClockView` also declare the variable (property) `int timerIntWhite` and set this variable from your View Controller after the View gets created, for example, in `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.timerIntWhite = self.timerIntWhite;
}
```

After doing this, `ClockView` can access it's own `timerIntWhite` variable:

```
- (void)start {

    timerIntWhite = self.timerIntWhite;
    randomTimerWhite = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0)target:self selector:@selector(updateWhiteClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I'm assuming that your `ClockViewController` class knows that its view IS-A `ClockView`. This is very important! Otherwise you'll get a warning.

I also want to mention that according to the MVC rules it's a better idea if your `ClockViewController` class takes care of the `NSTimer`. Views should be used to display information to the user only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just realized that many methods declared in my `ClockView` could also be declared in my `ClockViewController` by using properties in the `ClockView` and call them in my `ClockViewController`.